# Python assignment and how it works

Tags: python, variable-assignment

## What is the result of running the code below?

```
def insert(lst, em):
  # insert em in sequence lst
  i = 0
    while em > lst[i]:
      i = i+1
      if i == len(lst):
        break

  lst[:] = lst[:i] + [em] + lst[i:]

def choose(lst1, lst2):
  # pick list
  if lst1[0] < lst2[0]:
    return lst1
  else:
    return lst2

  l1 = [4]
  l2 = [6]
  insert(l2,5)
  insert(l1,5)
  l3 = choose(l1,l2)
  print l1,l3############
  insert(l3,1)
  print l1,l2,l3
    
    >>> ================================ RESTART ================================
    >>> 
    [1, 4, 5] [5, 6] [1, 4, 5]
```

So i know that before insert(l3,1) is called i get that L1=L3=[4 5]
and that L2 =[5 6] and i agree that after insert(L3,1) is called L3=[1 4 5] but i dont get why L1 also changes. Could anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: L1 and L3 are the same list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is happening step-by-step:

```
l1=[4]
l2=[6]
insert(l2,5)            # l2 = [5,6]
insert(l1,5)            # l1 = [4,5]
l3=choose(l1,l2)        # l3 = l1
print l1,l3
insert(l3,1)            # l3 = [1,4,5] and l1 = [1,4,5]
print l1,l2,l3
```

It is important to realize that when you say `l3 = choose(l1,l2)`, then `l3` is being assigned to exactly the same list as `l1` - that is, they point to exactly the same memory location. Therefore when you call `insert(l3,1)` you are also effectively inserting into `l1`.

This blog post might help explain more what's going on: http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list

Things would be different if you had `choose()` return a copy of `lst1` or `lst2` by using `list(lst1)` (or `list(lst2)`. For example, consider these sequence of statements:

```
x = [4,5,6]
id(x)         -- returns 4369059920
y = x
id(y)         -- returns 4369059920 (same as id(x))
y = list(x)   -- make a copy of x
id(y)         -- returns 4368985048 -- something different from id(x)
```